# Redis for C# / .NET and Windows development

Tags: c#, .net, windows, caching, redis

Wondering if Redis is the best option for caching stuff in C# / .NET development?

I was thinking that it's more about Linux etc.. But I'm trying to compare Redis vs Standard .NET caching mechanism in

```
System.Web.Caching
```

namespace.

Any thoughts?